# How to test cntk object detection example on custom image?

Tags: neural-network, object-detection, cntk

I am trying to run CNTK object detecion example on PascalVoc pretrained dataset. I run all required scripts in fastrcnn and get the visual output for the test data defined in dataset. Now I want to test network on my own image, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For Fast R-CNN you need a library that generates candidate ROIs (regions of interest) for your test images, e.g. [selective search](http://http%20://dlib.net/dlib/image_transforms/segment_image_abstract.h.html#find_candidate_object_locations).

If you want to evaluate a batch of images you can follow the description in the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN#train-on-your-own-data) to generate the test mapping file and the ROI coordinates (see `test.txt` and `test.rois.txt` in the corresponding `proc` sub folder). If you want to evaluate a single you would need to pass the image and the candidate ROI coordinates as inputs to cntk eval, similar to [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Image/TransferLearning/TransferLearning.py#L138):

```
# compute model output 
arguments = {loaded_model.arguments[0]: [hwc_format]} 
output = loaded_model.eval(arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

For FastRCNN you need to first run your custom image through Selective Search algorithm to generate ROIs (regions of interest) and then feed it to your model with sth like this:

`output = frcn_eval.eval({image_input: image_file, roi_proposals: roi_proposals})`

You can find more details here: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/release/latest/Examples/Image/Detection/FastRCNN

Anyway FastRCNN is not the most efficient way to do it because of usage of Selective Search (which is a real bottleneck here). If you want to improve the performance you can try FasterRCNN as it gets rid of SS algorithm and replaces it with Region Proposal Network which performs much, much better.
If you're interested, you can check my repo on GitHub: https://github.com/karolzak/CNTK-Hotel-pictures-classificator

Comment: Hi Karol, please be specific in your question. Try to focus on a topic you are interested and to provide a fragment of your work in the question as the link might change over time. If there is a technical issue you encountered describe the expected result, the actual result and how you tried to solve it. Questions that are focused on a single issue have better chances for a good answer.